Prettytable field spacing
How do I fix a misaligned table in pretty table?
This is what I typed
t.add_column('CHOICE',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'r')
t.add_column('MENU',['View BOD','View Doctors','View Nurses','View Helpers','View Other Staff','Add Doctor','Add Nurse','Add Helper','Add Other Staff'],'r')
print(t)

The | symbol is misaligned and it's getting printed immediately after my field element of second column.
I tried adding spaces manually, but it looked ugly. I also tried using _max_width, but it remained the same.
Output of the code given


I can't reproduce the problem. It looks fine for me in CMD and Powershell using prettytable 3.11.0.

What version of PrettyTable do you have? I have 3.11.0 - the table is smooth.

Are you using a non-monospace font? Looks like the width of your "I" indicates yes.

I agree with @Mr.Polywhirl that because you aren't using a monospaced font, you are getting unaligned output. Change the font of your console where this table is being outputted and try again.
